# Access Database of wordpress website using Amazon Web Services EC2.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have launched a wordpress website using Amazon Web Services. How I can access wordpress database like phpmysql in aws cloud and how many instances I can create freely using aws services. Please guide !

Comment: First Kamlesh Bhai Ramram :) Is your Mysql on a EC2 instance or on a RDS?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the wordpress instance by bitnami. Also got the answer of my question.

refer http://www.sakalmarathasamaz.com/bitnami/index.html